# How can I hang a poster on a metallic surface?

Tags: hanging

I want to put a poster on the sliding door of my closet, but the doors are metallic, so I can't really punch holes in them.

Also, it goes behind the other door when it slides, so the system holding it cannot be much thicker than the poster itself or the other door won't be able to slide in front of it.

Ideally, it needs to be held as flat as possible and with as little spacing between the poster and the door, as sagging could cause the poster to be torn when the other door slides back and forth in front of the poster.

Answer (score 4):

If it would work use magnetics. For supper flat use scotch tape, and tape the corners, or you could use poster adhesive strip but that will rase the edges a little.

Comment: Double sided sticky tape used to be a possibility. Haven't seen it in a few years, but haven't looked either. Just put in on the back of the poster, and stick on the door as your like.

Comment: you can put the tape on the edges to prevent the poster from catching on the door and tearing.

Answer (score 2):

For posters, I've always had the best luck with the blue colored varieties of sticky-tac or similar non-permanent doughy adhesives. Usually a piece in each corner the size of a dime has been more than enough to hang my posters in college.

Answer (score 0):

I go with these

[image: 3M Command Strips]

These function like universal velcro, that is,there is no hook side and one loop side.
I tend to hang large, relatively heavy posters. These are superior to tape which may cause tears.  I'd recommend putting the strips inside the corners by an inch or two ( depending on the size) to you won't see the edge of the strip. Plus, you can pull the poster off the door and readjust to make it square faster then re-taping it, should it not go on perfectly square the first time.
These aren't as thin as just using tape, but the thickness is negligible, a few millimetres.